# MVC4 not reading form postdata as expected. It is seeing the individual fields but not the full object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get a very simple project working as an address reader. For some reason when I setup the method for getting the Post data response from the edit form it will only work if I set it to look for the individual variables it properly reads the post data but if I set it up to accept the complex item it fails.

Here is my controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "";
    Address address = new Address();
    return View(address);
}


[HttpPost]
//public ActionResult Index(String Name, String Street1, String Street2, String City, String State, String Zip)
public ActionResult Index(Address model)
{
    Address address = model;

    //check ModelState
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(address);
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Save Success";
        address = new Address();
        return Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

If I use the commented out line all of them are properly filled in but if I use the `public ActionResult Index(Address model)` line the model variable remains empty.

Here is my view's form code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Address</legend>
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)</p>
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Street1, "Street address:") @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Street1, new Dictionary<string, object>{ {"tabindex" , "1"}, {"placeholder","Start typing to get suggestions"}})</p>
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Street2, "Street address 2:") @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Street2, new Dictionary<string, object>{ {"tabindex" , "2"} })</p>
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, "City:") @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, new Dictionary<string, object>{ {"tabindex" , "3"} })</p>
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, "State:") @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.State, new Dictionary<string, object>{ {"tabindex" , "4"} })</p>
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zip, "Zip:") @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Zip, new Dictionary<string, object>{ {"tabindex" , "5"} })</p>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" class="green" tabindex="6" value="Save">
    </fieldset>
}
```

The address class:

```
public class Address
{
    public String Name;
    public String Street1;
    public String Street2;
    public String City;
    public String State;
    public String Zip;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the model binding on post does not work if you have that signature but it does with the commented out one?

Comment: Try to decorate your BeginHtmlForm properly,`@using (Html.BeginForm("myAction", "myController", FormMethod.Post, 
                                      new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` Note the enctype html attribute is not required, just placed for completion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your model to this:

```
public class Address
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Street1 { get; set; }
    public String Street2 { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String State { get; set; }
    public String Zip { get; set; }
}
```

`Mvc` model binder only work on properties of complex type.